# Is there a way to handle all actions off of a UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Is there a way to use actions and selectors from Interface Builder to bind handlers to a UIToolbar?  Rather than enumerating the UIButtonBarItems and adding action selectors to each one at a time, I was hoping I could just implement a single method in my Controller, that would handle all of the buttons and handle the events by switching on either button's Tag or Identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to connect as many bar buttons as you like to the same `IBAction` method in Interface Builder. In the method, you can use the `sender` argument to see which button was tapped.

Comment: What I was looking to actually do is connect on the Toolbar itself, not the individual items in it.  OR, somehow catch all button-click type events in my controller, rather than having to individually bind to each control.